# Filtering elements based on condition and date filed

Tags: java, grails, groovy, filter

I am trying to filter my list based on the below condition.

check if any records with duplicate `name` and `employee` fields. If it has duplicates then keep only the element whose `date` field value is latest and ignoring other duplicate values.

input list:

```
[{
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "10/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "John",
    employee: "no",
    date: "14/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "14/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "Doe",
    employess: "yes",
    date: "10/01/2020"
},
{
    name: "Bob",
    employess: "yes",
    date: "09/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "Doe",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "01/12/2019"
},
{
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "no",
    date: "01/12/2019"
}]
```

Desirable output:

```
[{
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "14/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "John",
    employee: "no",
    date: "14/12/2020"
},
{
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "no",
    date: "01/12/2019"
},
{
    name: "Doe",
    employess: "yes",
    date: "10/01/2020"
}]
```

I tried with `findAll()` method but not able to get desired results.

Comment: Show what you tried and how it failed so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `inject` would help:

```
def list = [[
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "10/12/2020"
],
[
    name: "John",
    employee: "no",
    date: "14/12/2020"
],
[
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "14/12/2020"
],
[
    name: "Doe",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "10/01/2020"
],
[
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "09/12/2020"
],
[
    name: "Doe",
    employee: "yes",
    date: "01/12/2019"
],
[
    name: "Bob",
    employee: "no",
    date: "01/12/2019"
]]

def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')

def result = list.inject( [:] ){ res, curr ->
  Date date = sdf.parse curr.date
  String key = curr.name + '_' + curr.employee
  if( res[ key ]?.date < date ){
    res[ key ] = curr + [ date:date ]
  }
  res
}.values().collect{ it + [ date:sdf.format( it.date ) ] }.join('\n')

println result
```

prints

```
[name:Bob, employee:yes, date:14/12/2020]
[name:John, employee:no, date:14/12/2020]
[name:Doe, employee:yes, date:10/01/2020]
[name:Bob, employee:no, date:01/12/2019]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupBy` the sub map of `name` and `employee` and then find the
max `date` in the values of the grouped items.  E.g.

```
def data = [
    [a: 1, b: 2, c: 0],
    [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3],
    [a: 2, b: 3, c: 0],
]

data.groupBy{
    it.subMap(["a", "b"])
}.collect{ k, v -> 
    k + [c: v*.c.max()] 
}
// -> [[a:1, b:2, c:3], [a:2, b:3, c:0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can collect the initial list as nested maps.
For example, first you can group records by name. Then group by an employee. Eventually, you will get the following Map<String, Map<String, List>.
Now you can fetch a record by keys in maps and the latest date in the list.